Are the following two pieces of pytorch training code equivalent
I'm trying to adapt a two-stage model so I can train it in an end-to-end way, but for some complicated reasons, I need to modify the output of the first stage, so I'm wondering if the following two pieces of code are equivalent.
class Net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

class Net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net2, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

model1 = Net1()
model2 = Net2()

input1 = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]])

target = torch.tensor([[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]])

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer1 = torch.optim.SGD(model1.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer2 = torch.optim.SGD(model2.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for epoch in range(10000):
    optimizer1.zero_grad()
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    output1 = model1(input1)
    output2 = model2(output1)
    loss = criterion(output2, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer1.step()
    optimizer2.step()

class TwoNets(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TwoNets, self).__init__()
        self.model1 = Net1()
        self.model2 = Net2()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model1(x)
        x = self.model2(x)
        return x

model = TwoNets()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for epoch in range(10000):
    output.zero_grad()
    output = model(input1)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

In addition, does the output of the first piece of code still make sense if I shuffle the output of the first stage? Like this:
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

model1 = Net()
model2 = Net()

input1 = torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]])

target = torch.tensor([[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]])

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer1 = torch.optim.SGD(model1.parameters(), lr=0.1)
optimizer2 = torch.optim.SGD(model2.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for epoch in range(10000):
    optimizer1.zero_grad()
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    output1 = model1(input1)
    random.shuffle(output1)                                           #shuffle output1
    output2 = model2(output1)
    loss = criterion(output2, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer1.step()
    optimizer2.step()


Have you tried running this code? model1 outputs a 1-dimensional feature but model2 expects a 2-dimensional input. I would expect both versions to crash.
